# Wordpress Caching Plugins - When Should I Use Them?

Tags: wordpress, cdn, traffic, cloudflare

In the past two months I have had a site of mine really take off (at least in my mind) and get around 2600 uniques, and 10,000 pages views a month.  I'm on a VPS that performs pretty well, but I have experimented with the W3 Total Cache Wordpress plugin, as well as using CloudFlare.  I really struggle in being able to tell if I get much overall performance improvement from these plugins and services.

My question is, when should I really be using a caching service?  Is there a certain traffic level that makes these plugins or services make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you don't need to worry about caching at the moment. Or install something like WordPress Super Cache, set the most compatible caching level and forget about it until you'll have 10-20x higher traffic.

Comment: From the lack in performance difference I tend to agree, is there any rule of thumb or reasoning behind your answer?

Comment: Yes, "don't fix it when it is not broken" and "Keep it simple".

Comment: I get where you are coming from, and agree with that life principal, but there is no technical reason for your answer. We should be able to make decisions based on measured analytics, or some base of logic, right?

Answer (score 0):

"I really struggle in being able to tell if I get much overall performance improvement from these plugins and services."

Try running tests with the services on/off on something like webpagetest.org or pingdom.com. This should help you find out how effective CloudFlare or the caching plugins are versus going direct.

Answer (score 0):

The effectiveness of cache-plugins highly depends on your visitors. If mainly anonymous, fine, if not you need more powerful methods.

Since you're on VPS i'd recommend:

- Skip apache if used (mem-hog in vps), go nginx or cherokee.
- Install xcache or similar
- Use php-fpm

regards,
/t